# Attempting to install any Linux distro on HP Envy x360 worked in the past, but now results in a black screen after I select "Try without installing"

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, hp

I have tried Ubuntu/Linux Mint/Fedora in an attempt to install Linux on my laptop. Each time I try, I get a black screen after trying the system equivalent of *Try without installing* on the bootable USB. I've tried this on a friend's computer (where it worked), so it seems to be an issue with mine specifically.

I have disabled safeboot, tried with legacy mode on and off. I have tried `nomodeset` replacing `quiet splash` or before it. None of these seems to have worked. I have put Linux on [this computer](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-envy-x360-convertible-laptop-15t-1za23av-1) before (Ubuntu specifically) but now I am having a very tough time with it.

This question is not a duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) because as I have mentioned, I already tried the `nomodeset` option described, I also already tried secure boot off and legacy mode on/off. There's no error code and I don't get the first image shown in the first picture.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as most(all?) of the problems/solutions listed there I have attempted to try

Comment: Edited the post in an attempt to add more details and explain more. This post is not a duplicate as far as I can tell

Comment: try using a different USB device. I've had similar issues before where, even though other computers had no issue reading the USB, the one I wanted to install to wouldn't read it properly.

Comment: There are 51 answers in the duplicate.  Have you tried all of those?  MD5SUM? New USB? If yes, please [edit] your question with the results of all.  If the first answer doesn't work, please keep on reading...  **;-)**

Comment: This laptop has dual graphics. Could you please edit the BIOS setting and make sure that only one of them is enabled, preferably the integrated Intel Graphics adapter?